# Filtering in asp grid having paging

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have an asp grid with records ranging to up to 100k (maximum). I have done paging with 4000 records per page.

Now my client needs to have a row under the header column with textbox for searching. Something like we found in devexpress controls.

How could be the architecture?

I started like:

1. Whenever the user enters something in textbox and hits enter, a webmethod   is called for filtering the result. Since the webmethod is static how can I bind the filtered data back to grid?
2. Is this the right approach? I am afraid like this will have an impact on pagination.

Comment: ASP.NET or Classic ASP?

Comment: @Keith  ASP.Net grid